# Is there is notion of Fourier transform of distribution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

We note that every tempered distribution is a distribution.

> Can we find  a example of distribution which is NOT a tempered distribution?
>
> Can we talk  of Fourier transform of that distribution? If yes, how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=e^{|x|^2}$ is a distribution (since it is locally integrable) but is not a tempered distribution. Trying to define its Fourier transform the same way it is done for tempered distributions, that is,
$$
\langle\hat f,\phi\rangle=\langle f,\hat\phi\rangle,\quad\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n),
$$
we run into problems: $\hat\phi\not\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the right hand side is not defined for all $\phi$.